# Basic rotation using Snap.svg

Tags: javascript, css, svg, snap.svg

I am trying to rotate the svg as it translates along, but i cant make it rotate on its axis. Is there a way to make it rotate on its own axis ?

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tuqbf9ub/81/)

js Code

```
var paper = Snap('#svg');
matrix = new Snap.Matrix().translate(630, -95);
var start_gear = paper.path("M51.7,29.5v-7.2h-5.2c-0.5-3.1-1.6-6-3.3-8.5l3.4-3.4l-5.1-5.1l-3.2,3.2c-2.6-2-5.6-3.4-8.8-4V0.3h-7.1v4.1 c-3.4,0.5-6.5,1.7-9.2,3.6l-2.8-2.8l-5.1,5.1L8,12.9c-2,2.7-3.3,5.8-3.8,9.2H0v7.1h4.2c0.6,3.4,2,6.6,4,9.2l-2.8,2.8l5.1,5.1 l2.9-2.9c2.6,1.7,5.6,2.9,8.9,3.4v5.3h7.2v-5.4c3.1-0.6,6-1.9,8.5-3.7l3.6,3.6l5.1-5.1l-3.7-3.7c1.7-2.5,2.9-5.3,3.5-8.3H51.7z M25.8,38.1c-6.6,0-12-5.4-12-12c0-6.6,5.4-12,12-12c6.6,0,12,5.4,12,12C37.8,32.8,32.4,38.1,25.8,38.1z").transform(matrix);
start_gear.attr({fill: "#e8434d"});
start_gear.animate({ transform: 't630, 240 r540,22,20' }, 3000, mina.bounce);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "rotate on its own axis"?  The cog **is** rotating on its own axis.

Comment: Do you mean like http://jsfiddle.net/tuqbf9ub/82/ ? As Paul mentions it is on its own axis, but varying a little, not sure if thats the bit you don't want or not.

Comment: @Ian yes i dont even want that the variation occurs

Comment: So are you saying that fiddle is what you want ? I can set it as an answer if so. It's not quite clear if you want something else as well though.

Comment: @Ian yes like i kept on tweaking with values to reduce the variation, but i was hoping is there a way to achieve zero variation by using some common procedure for every rotation based animation. But i would like the same fiddle with zero variation with snap.svg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't include your own center of rotation, Snap will use its calculated bounding box center to rotate around. So it's as simple as removing that.

```
start_gear.animate({ transform: 't630, 240 r540' }, 3000, mina.bounce);
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tuqbf9ub/82/)

If you only want to rotate, AND the element already has a transform applied to it, you need to include the previous transform, so it doesn't get overwritten. To get the previous transform, it's simply element.transform(). So the full command would be...

```
start_gear.animate({ transform: start_gear.transform() + 'r540' }, 3000, mina.bounce);
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tuqbf9ub/85/)

Comment: but is it possible only to rotate without having to translate the gear

Comment: Thank you so much i have some minor questions regarding animations based on snap. What if i want to chain these animation such after that gear falls down, i also need it rotate infinitely. But if i chain it the function makes the gear go back to the starting point and animating in different way

Comment: You need to think about what combinations you have. Combining rotations and translations after each other, can sometimes get a little messy. To get around that, you could place the element in a group. Translate the group and rotate the element, and use callbacks to loop the function calls. Example http://jsfiddle.net/tuqbf9ub/91/ Also take a look at the nextFrame func in http://svg.dabbles.info/snaptut-animateframe

Answer (score 0):

See this [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/00ojvkzz/), I used TimelineMax.js lib. it is Super easy and helpful in animation !

HTML code :

```
<svg id="svg" width="80vw" height="60vh" viewBox="0 0 1300 250">
<path class="myPath" d="M51.7,29.5v-7.2h-5.2c-0.5-3.1-1.6-6-3.3-8.5l3.4-3.4l-5.1-5.1l-3.2,3.2c-2.6-2-5.6-3.4-8.8-4V0.3h-7.1v4.1 c-3.4,0.5-6.5,1.7-9.2,3.6l-2.8-2.8l-5.1,5.1L8,12.9c-2,2.7-3.3,5.8-3.8,9.2H0v7.1h4.2c0.6,3.4,2,6.6,4,9.2l-2.8,2.8l5.1,5.1 l2.9-2.9c2.6,1.7,5.6,2.9,8.9,3.4v5.3h7.2v-5.4c3.1-0.6,6-1.9,8.5-3.7l3.6,3.6l5.1-5.1l-3.7-3.7c1.7-2.5,2.9-5.3,3.5-8.3H51.7z M25.8,38.1c-6.6,0-12-5.4-12-12c0-6.6,5.4-12,12-12c6.6,0,12,5.4,12,12C37.8,32.8,32.4,38.1,25.8,38.1z"></path>
```

JS code:

```
/*
var paper = Snap('#svg');

matrix = new Snap.Matrix().translate(630, -95);
var start_gear = paper.path("M51.7,29.5v-7.2h-5.2c-0.5-3.1-1.6-6-3.3-8.5l3.4-3.4l-5.1-5.1l-3.2,3.2c-2.6-2-5.6-3.4-8.8-4V0.3h-7.1v4.1 c-3.4,0.5-6.5,1.7-9.2,3.6l-2.8-2.8l-5.1,5.1L8,12.9c-2,2.7-3.3,5.8-3.8,9.2H0v7.1h4.2c0.6,3.4,2,6.6,4,9.2l-2.8,2.8l5.1,5.1 l2.9-2.9c2.6,1.7,5.6,2.9,8.9,3.4v5.3h7.2v-5.4c3.1-0.6,6-1.9,8.5-3.7l3.6,3.6l5.1-5.1l-3.7-3.7c1.7-2.5,2.9-5.3,3.5-8.3H51.7z M25.8,38.1c-6.6,0-12-5.4-12-12c0-6.6,5.4-12,12-12c6.6,0,12,5.4,12,12C37.8,32.8,32.4,38.1,25.8,38.1z").transform(matrix);
start_gear.attr({fill: "#e8434d"});

start_gear.animate({ transform: 't630, 240 r540,22,20' }, 3000, mina.bounce); */



var tl = new TimelineMax();

// Settings ...

tl.set(".myPath", {
    x: 630,
    y: -95,
    fill: "#e8434d",
    transformOrigin: "center"
})

// Animatiion ...

tl.to(".myPath", 3 , { 
    //x : "+= 500",
    y: "+= 400",
    rotation: "630",
    ease: Bounce.easeOut
});
```